# cannot get author comment using facebook graph v3.1 api even using page token

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, codeigniter

I am new to the Facebook Graph API to get post and comment and also I'm using my page token to do that here the details, also I can post, comment, and reply with that token.

[detail token page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfCrd.jpg)

[my page](https://www.facebook.com/rainfieldCloud)

```
$data = (new FacebookRequest(
            $this->data['token'], 'GET', '/me/posts'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->getPropertyAsArray("data");
    foreach ($data as $key => $post){
        $postId = $post->getProperty('id');
        $comments = (new FacebookRequest(
        $this->data['token'], 'GET', '/'.$postId.'/comments',array('fields'=>'message,created_time,from')
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        print_r($value->comments);
    }
```

and here is the response:

[response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EID9d.jpg)

the field from won't show from the other user

Answer (score 0):

Try adding permissions to your facebook app. Some permissions are

```
   publish_actions       
   manage_pages
   pages_manage_cta
   pages_manage_instant_articles
   pages_show_list
   pages_messaging
   pages_messaging_phone_number
   pages_messaging_subscriptions
   pages_messaging_payments
   publish_pages
   read_page_mailboxes
   business_management
   user_managed_groups
```

for more information visit this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview

Comment: If you ask too many permissions Facebook will require you to submit an app review for each permission.

Comment: how about this https://ibb.co/fh319K still cant get field from, can you give me a screenshot that u can get field from ?

Comment: I managed to get post of my account, have a look at here https://imgur.com/a/wov7SUI please note i only put 3 permissions user_posts, email, public_profile

Comment: Not found image, thanks for your answer btw, maybe i ll try with new account

Comment: the image is loading slow, but you can view it.